# Adding a movie with multiple values to my Mongo DB table

Tags: python, python-3.x

Im trying to add a movie to my mongo DB table but it is only included the last value could someone tell me where I am going wring the code I am using in my python file is below:

```
@app.route('/insert_movie', methods=['POST'])
def insert_movie():

    movie_added = {'title': request.form.get('title')}

    {'imdb.rating': request.form.get('imdb.rating')}

    {'tomato.rating': request.form.get('tomato.rating')}

    {'year': request.form.get('year')}

    {'runtime': request.form.get('runtime')}

    {'actors': request.form.get('actors')}

    {'director': request.form.get('director')}

    {'plot': request.form.get('plot')}

    mongo.db.movie_information.insert_one(movie_added)

    return redirect(url_for('get_movies'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting all of the fields into a single object (see below). That way, when you insert one movie, that movie contains all of the fields from the one object that you sent.

```
movie_added = {'title': request.form.get('title'),

'imdb.rating': request.form.get('imdb.rating'),

'tomato.rating': request.form.get('tomato.rating'),

'year': request.form.get('year'),

'runtime': request.form.get('runtime'),

'actors': request.form.get('actors'),

'director': request.form.get('director'),

'plot': request.form.get('plot')}

mongo.db.movie_information.insert_one(movie_added)

return redirect(url_for('get_movies'))`
```